# AttributeError: tuple obj has no attribute in .py script with PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, attributeerror, pysimplegui

I've written a Python script that cycles through a folder structure and looks inside the files for a given value. The script works well, but now I'm trying to add a GUI and can't get passed this error. The error occurs when clicking 'search' in the gui, triggering the event.

*File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Python Scripts\FileContentsSearcherwWithFileWrite_GUIv02.py", line 66, in 
event, values = window().read
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'*

I *think* I understand that there is a tuple somewhere in the script that the window is trying to read/display, but I can't figure out what it could be. Is anyone able to help?

Thanks

```
import os, PySimpleGUI as sg

document_ext = ['.SVG', '.txt', '.XML']

layout = [
           [
            sg.Text("This program can be used to search for a particular \nterm in all files under the folder location provided.") 
           ],
           [
            sg.Listbox(document_ext, size=(10,5), key="-File_Ext-")
           ],
          [
            sg.Text('What would you like to search for?')
           ],
           [
            sg.InputText(size=(30,5), key="-Search_Term-")
           ],
           [
            sg.Text("Choose Folder to Search:")
            ],
           [
            sg.In(size=(30,5), key="-FOLDER-"),
            sg.FolderBrowse()
           ],
           [
            sg.Text("Where Should Report Be Saved?")
            ],
           [
            sg.In(size=(30,5), key="-FOLDER2-"),
            sg.FolderBrowse()
           ],
           [
            sg.Button(button_text="Search")    
           ],
           [
            sg.Text(key="-Output-", size=(30,5))    
           ]
        ]

window = sg.Window("File Contents Searcher", layout)#, margins=(200,200))

def main(svalue, location, ext):
    number_found = 0
    search_results = ""
    os.chdir(location)
    for dpath, dname, fname in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        for name in fname:
            pat = os.path.join(dpath,name)
            if name.endswith(ext):
                with open(pat) as f:
                    if svalue in f.read():
                        number_found += 1
                        search_results += "--- \nFilename: {} \nFilepath: {} \n".format(name, pat)
    search_results_head = "\"{}\" was found in {} files. \n \n".format(svalue, number_found)
    output = "RESULTS \n \n" + search_results_head + search_results
    return output, search_results_head

def create_log(sl, s_res):
     os.chdir(sl)
     print(os.getcwd())
     with open("FileSearchResults.txt", "w") as f:
         f.write(s_res)
     return "Report Saved"

while True:
    event, values = window().read
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == "Search":
        m = main("-Search_Term-", r"-FOLDER-", "-File_Ext-")
        c = create_log(r"-FOLDER2-", m[0])
        window("-Output-").update(print(m[1] + " " + c))
window.close()
```

Comment: Wrong statement, it should be `event, values = window.read()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this.

```
import os, PySimpleGUI as sg

document_ext = ['.SVG', '.txt', '.XML']

layout = [
           [
            sg.Text("This program can be used to search for a particular \nterm in all files under the folder location provided.") 
           ],
           [
            sg.Listbox(document_ext, size=(10,5), key="-File_Ext-")
           ],
          [
            sg.Text('What would you like to search for?')
           ],
           [
            sg.InputText(size=(30,5), key="-Search_Term-")
           ],
           [
            sg.Text("Choose Folder to Search:")
            ],
           [
            sg.In(size=(30,5), key="-FOLDER-"),
            sg.FolderBrowse()
           ],
           [
            sg.Text("Where Should Report Be Saved?")
            ],
           [
            sg.In(size=(30,5), key="-FOLDER2-"),
            sg.FolderBrowse()
           ],
           [
            sg.Button(button_text="Search")    
           ],
           [
            sg.Multiline(key="-Output-", size=(30,5))    
           ]
        ]

window = sg.Window("File Contents Searcher", layout)#, margins=(200,200))

def main(svalue, location, ext):
    number_found = 0
    search_results = ""
    location = (values["-FOLDER-"]) # Set values to window.read() values
    svalue= (values["-Search_Term-"]) # Ditto for this
    ext = str(values["-File_Ext-"][0].lower()) # Needs this to choose value and make it case insensitive

    #os.chdir(location) # Don't need
    for dpath, dname, fname in os.walk(location): #Hardcoded to value above
        for name in fname:
            pat = os.path.join(dpath,name)
            if name.endswith(ext):
                with open(pat) as f:
                    if svalue in f.read():
                        number_found += 1
                        search_results += "--- \nFilename: {} \nFilepath: {} \n".format(name, pat)
    search_results_head = "\"{}\" was found in {} files. \n \n".format(svalue, number_found)
    output = "RESULTS \n \n" + search_results_head + search_results
    return output, search_results_head

def create_log(sl, s_res):
     s1 = (values["-FOLDER2-"])  # Hardcoded again
     print(os.getcwd())
     with open("FileSearchResults.txt", "w") as f:
         f.write(s_res)
     return "Report Saved"

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == "Search":
        m = main("-Search_Term-", "-FOLDER-", "-File_Ext-")
        print(m)
        c = create_log(r"-FOLDER2-", m[0])
        window["-Output-"].update(m[1] + " " + c)
window.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Jason, that works great. I haven't done much with python and even less with the GUI module; from looking at your solution I take it local variables always need to be explicitly assigned to the GUI values?
Two other Qs to help me understand your solution: 1) why does the "-File_Ext-" value need a position - [0] - to work when it's a single choice? 2) you added a 'print(m)' to the while clause - was this just to help you see the output as you looked into it?

Comment: Yes, you need to tie your GUI code to your python code by telling what each variable refers to. On the [0] question, remove the [0] and print out the value and you'll see that it is a dictionary value. Per the docs, the return values from a listbox element will be a list of results. Not a single result.because you could select more than one result. And yes, the last print statement was just for clarification. Hope this helps. I too am learning.